# Azure IoT SDK - async response to Direct Method

Tags: azure-iot-sdk

Similar to this question and solution: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/issues/1081

The caveat being I don't see how I can obtain the methodId necessary for delaying a response when using the convenience layer API. When the callback which was registered with IoTHubClient_SetDeviceMethodCallback() is called, setting payload response to NULL will result in no response being sent by SDK- I'd like to get the methodId in this callback to use later when response is ready.

I'd like to later call IoTHubClient_DeviceMethodResponse(), but how to obtain methodId necessary for this function?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution: need to register another callback to handle asynchronous direct methods. See: IoTHub_SetDeviceMethodCallbackEx()

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-c-sdk-ref/iothub-client-h/iothubclient-setdevicemethodcallback-ex